Fiting Damped Sine with high Correlation
I want to fit the function
$$f_t(x_1,x_2,x_3) = -x_1\exp \left(-\frac{t}{x_2} \right)\sin(2\pi x_3t)$$
which is basically a damped sine. This works quite well with non-linear LSQ. However, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are highly correlated (the correlation coefficient between the two is ~0.8. I assume this is because they both stretch the amplitude, so it's a numerical phenomenon, not a physical one.
How could I solve this correlation problem? My first idea was to use log, but sine puts a spoke in the wheel here because it can be negative.
Here is a sample data set:
8.966643363237380981e-03
7.126736454665660858e-03
5.043082870543003082e-03
8.055254817008972168e-03
-1.046796236187219620e-02
-4.413136839866638184e-02
-6.652563065290451050e-02
-9.456811845302581787e-02
-9.730125963687896729e-02
-8.434351533651351929e-02
-7.109113037586212158e-02
-4.091500863432884216e-02
-3.176774084568023682e-02
5.255106836557388306e-03
4.680778086185455322e-02
7.985781878232955933e-02
1.143909692764282227e-01
1.152194067835807800e-01
1.154708266258239746e-01
1.134108528494834900e-01
1.148287281394004822e-01
1.178659945726394653e-01
8.650591969490051270e-02
4.921977967023849487e-02
2.861171029508113861e-03
-3.203808516263961792e-02
-5.455151945352554321e-02
-7.957706600427627563e-02
-9.179902821779251099e-02
-1.074272245168685913e-01
-1.003252416849136353e-01
-8.007297664880752563e-02
-7.094771414995193481e-02
-4.000033810734748840e-02
-1.795851066708564758e-02
1.122475229203701019e-02
5.220469459891319275e-02
7.886603474617004395e-02
1.012783572077751160e-01
1.043289378285408020e-01
1.034792512655258179e-01
1.047663465142250061e-01
8.830827474594116211e-02
7.594904303550720215e-02
4.094155877828598022e-02
9.239769540727138519e-03
-1.795692183077335358e-02
-4.233868420124053955e-02
-5.987219512462615967e-02
-7.998567819595336914e-02
-8.714827150106430054e-02
-9.531795233488082886e-02
-9.078027307987213135e-02
-5.712023004889488220e-02
-3.989974036812782288e-02
-2.044359967112541199e-02
-3.706025192514061928e-03
2.030327357351779938e-02
5.653142929077148438e-02
7.321128249168395996e-02
9.049408882856369019e-02
9.152477979660034180e-02
8.801533281803131104e-02
8.417512476444244385e-02
6.988789886236190796e-02
5.741269886493682861e-02
2.670256607234477997e-02
8.562316652387380600e-04
-2.097478136420249939e-02
-4.271446168422698975e-02
-5.654580891132354736e-02
-7.547828555107116699e-02
-7.700698822736740112e-02
-8.413653075695037842e-02
-7.705481350421905518e-02
-5.116409435868263245e-02
-3.106704540550708771e-02
-1.177223585546016693e-02
-1.182136475108563900e-03
1.680264063179492950e-02
4.949522018432617188e-02
7.107245177030563354e-02
8.223304897546768188e-02
8.000987023115158081e-02
7.090825587511062622e-02
7.460233569145202637e-02
6.116909906268119812e-02
4.333891719579696655e-02
1.977621763944625854e-02
-1.619271119125187397e-03
-2.732517383992671967e-02
-5.296600237488746643e-02
-5.762952566146850586e-02
-6.103414297103881836e-02
-7.188842445611953735e-02
-6.851723790168762207e-02
-5.959088355302810669e-02
-4.201127216219902039e-02
-2.786801382899284363e-02
-8.429488167166709900e-03
8.879688568413257599e-03
2.615911699831485748e-02
4.758974537253379822e-02
5.709838122129440308e-02
6.797258555889129639e-02
6.475507467985153198e-02
6.190078333020210266e-02
5.901395156979560852e-02
4.648062959313392639e-02
3.441854938864707947e-02
1.166252885013818741e-02
-1.656315289437770844e-02
-3.017767891287803650e-02
-4.635406658053398132e-02
-5.323788523674011230e-02
-6.086890399456024170e-02
-6.824316829442977905e-02
-6.135406717658042908e-02
-5.258157476782798767e-02
-3.540666401386260986e-02
-1.499837636947631836e-02
1.516101183369755745e-03
2.078760042786598206e-02
3.496176749467849731e-02
4.822085797786712646e-02
5.765317752957344055e-02
6.697658449411392212e-02
7.144401222467422485e-02
6.556848436594009399e-02
6.032085046172142029e-02
3.653117641806602478e-02
2.662193030118942261e-02
1.007632073014974594e-02
-9.435101412236690521e-03
-2.157452702522277832e-02
-3.613629564642906189e-02
-4.917232692241668701e-02
-6.027804687619209290e-02
-5.866177007555961609e-02
-5.633534863591194153e-02
-5.186115205287933350e-02
-3.427491337060928345e-02
-2.590672858059406281e-02
-1.031847856938838959e-02
1.235279906541109085e-02
3.301437199115753174e-02
5.110748484730720520e-02
6.343439221382141113e-02
6.594293564558029175e-02
6.682319194078445435e-02
6.160676106810569763e-02
5.030431225895881653e-02
3.381286561489105225e-02
2.440843917429447174e-02
5.941255483776330948e-03
-8.078302256762981415e-03
-2.310442365705966949e-02
-4.405274614691734314e-02
-5.057166516780853271e-02
-5.930565297603607178e-02
-5.808024853467941284e-02
-4.655136913061141968e-02
-4.019899666309356689e-02
-2.826237119734287262e-02
-1.274662837386131287e-02
5.729906260967254639e-03
1.752580702304840088e-02
3.002178668975830078e-02
5.149123072624206543e-02
6.172033399343490601e-02
6.872560083866119385e-02
6.027625873684883118e-02
4.965799674391746521e-02
4.108787700533866882e-02
3.113434836268424988e-02
1.330660656094551086e-02
-2.544979332014918327e-03
-1.603539288043975830e-02
-3.351216390728950500e-02
-4.812623560428619385e-02
-5.704763159155845642e-02
-6.039728596806526184e-02
-5.585307255387306213e-02
-5.079874396324157715e-02
-3.386097401380538940e-02
-1.590761914849281311e-02
-4.078523852513171732e-05
1.596046239137649536e-02
2.568203210830688477e-02
3.674203529953956604e-02
5.081457272171974182e-02
6.123724952340126038e-02
5.831237509846687317e-02
6.128136813640594482e-02
4.769354686141014099e-02
3.437312319874763489e-02
2.532031759619712830e-02
1.177975069731473923e-02
-3.942175302654504776e-03
-1.550295483320951462e-02
-2.673129364848136902e-02
-4.338959977030754089e-02
-4.467118531465530396e-02
-4.931975901126861572e-02
-4.732083156704902649e-02
-3.656756877899169922e-02
-2.565709874033927917e-02
-9.383687749505043030e-03
4.668733163271099329e-04
1.137403771281242371e-02
2.586179040372371674e-02
3.408668562769889832e-02
3.940056636929512024e-02
4.884324595332145691e-02
4.557005688548088074e-02
5.018871277570724487e-02
4.997388646006584167e-02
3.947301954030990601e-02
1.628736965358257294e-02
7.828809320926666260e-03
-1.023719459772109985e-02
-3.241145610809326172e-02
-3.447027876973152161e-02
-4.120336100459098816e-02
-4.191961884498596191e-02
-3.970159217715263367e-02
-3.745245561003684998e-02
-3.149121999740600586e-02
-1.911726407706737518e-02
-9.279709309339523315e-03
-1.297335838899016380e-04
1.800106093287467957e-02
2.499813959002494812e-02
3.577487170696258545e-02
4.627541452646255493e-02
4.831165447831153870e-02
4.556743055582046509e-02
4.043996334075927734e-02
3.430198132991790771e-02
3.063761629164218903e-02
1.786389760673046112e-02
3.902226686477661133e-03
-6.779014598578214645e-03
-1.684470474720001221e-02
-2.835024707019329071e-02
-3.767036274075508118e-02
-4.257490485906600952e-02
-3.835468739271163940e-02
-3.056643903255462646e-02
-3.208297118544578552e-02
-2.711975574493408203e-02
-1.560773421078920364e-02
-7.702879520365968347e-05
1.675285585224628448e-02
2.644225209951400757e-02
3.312706202268600464e-02
4.268310219049453735e-02
4.675029590725898743e-02
4.068629816174507141e-02
3.119379281997680664e-02
2.545884251594543457e-02
2.103446610271930695e-02
1.682285033166408539e-02
8.208380895666778088e-04
-7.619312033057212830e-03
-2.293961681425571442e-02
-3.127962723374366760e-02
-3.351957723498344421e-02
-3.265508264303207397e-02
-2.606210857629776001e-02
-2.035724185407161713e-02
-1.527934148907661438e-02
-6.632489617913961411e-03
2.471984829753637314e-03
1.027685403823852539e-02
2.019842527806758881e-02
2.581395581364631653e-02
3.401661664247512817e-02
3.485165908932685852e-02
4.239124804735183716e-02
3.653428331017494202e-02
2.645356580615043640e-02
2.404482103884220123e-02
1.365008018910884857e-02
8.740883320569992065e-03
2.099668141454458237e-03
-5.315508693456649780e-03
-1.239924691617488861e-02
-2.020017430186271667e-02
-2.049838192760944366e-02
-2.618686482310295105e-02
-2.416406944394111633e-02
-1.855812594294548035e-02
-1.436555664986371994e-02
-6.249126512557268143e-03
-1.453479635529220104e-03
2.852279692888259888e-03
9.595580399036407471e-03
2.137734368443489075e-02
2.846152707934379578e-02


Please joint to the question a representative example of data (numerical not graphical).

Thanks, I have added one

Isn't there a missing t in the sine? What about the values of t?

Oh sorry, you are right. Was a mistake in writing. f is x_3 and t is known

If you ask me, it's a good question if their should be actually correlation. Thanks for the inputs, I will rethink about my problem

How do you mean?

What is your data ? Is it $t$ or is it $f$ ? In order to fit the damped sine function and to compute the parameters $x_1,x_2,x_3$ one need data $t$ AND data $f$.

@bilaljo, Could you share the time measurement as well?
